# OpenCV Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I am trying to run an opencv project by xcode6.

Now, I want to use Xcode 6 as development environment. But I get an Apple Mach-O Linker error. I add opencv2.framework in project. But i can't  build project. That is the error;

```
Ld /Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.app/OpenCVTest normal x86_64
    cd /Users/algorist/Desktop/Projeler/OpenCvTest/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -FOpenCVTest/Plugins/com.algorist.ocr -filelist /Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Intermediates/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OpenCVTest.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework TesseractOCR -framework opencv2 -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Accelerate -framework GLKit -lstdc++.6.0.9 -framework CoreImage -lc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Intermediates/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OpenCVTest_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/algorist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-gngmfszrvncpuqfhljuggdtereui/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.app/OpenCVTest

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CVBufferRelease", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_CVBufferRetain", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferCreate", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferRelease", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey", referenced from:
      -[CvVideoCamera pixelBufferFromCGImage:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferHeightKey", referenced from:
      CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
      CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera createVideoDataOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
      -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferWidthKey", referenced from:
      CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XCode:

- Go to project settings
- Go to Link Binary With Libraries
- Make sure that the following iOS Frameworks are added:
  1) `AVFoundation.framework`
  2) `AssetsLibrary.framework`
  3) `CoreMedia.framework`
  4) `CoreVideo.framework`

It's trying to use the openCV methods with the same name, so supply it with the right headers and you should be good to go.

Thanks to [Erzekiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791407/erz%c3%a9kiel) for the inspiration/help.

Comment: Thanks for answere.After a while, I've found this solution. It brought me a long time deal. It has been a good explanation for people living in this issue.